# How to execute selenium UI test scripts from aws code pipeline

Tags: aws-codepipeline

I have a requirement of building CI/CD pipeline in aws for which we are using code build, code deploy and code pipeline, i have setup everything i have built the code and deployed the angular UI to linux environment, but i got struck to execute the selenium test scripts after deploy step.

Could any one guide me how to execute the selenium test scripts from code pipeline after the deploy stage has completed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

AWS CodeBuild supports custom containers so we can use the Selenium/standalone-Firefox and Selenium/standalone-Chrome containers, which include prebuild Firefox and Chrome browsers, respectively

Please see the details in this blog:

[1] Using AWS CodePipeline, AWS CodeBuild, and AWS Lambda for Serverless Automated UI Testing - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/using-aws-codepipeline-aws-codebuild-and-aws-lambda-for-serverless-automated-ui-testing/